# OpenCV: stack corruption after minMaxIdx

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

Using OpenCV (2.49 binaries) with MSVC 2013, the debug runtime reports a stack corruption when using `cv::minMaxIdx` in this short code:

```
    cv::MatND hist;
    int histSize[] = { 256 };
    float range[] = { 0, 256 };
    const float* histRange[] = { range };

    cv::calcHist(&image, 1, { 0 }, cv::Mat(), hist, 1, histSize, histRange, true /* uniform */, true /* accumulate */);
    // this line provokes a stack corruption
    cv::minMaxIdx(hist, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, &maxIdx);
```

I can see the histogram in the debugger, all values and variables look correct. The problem does not occur in Release mode but I suspect that's only because the checks are not running. Changing `hist` to `hist.col(0)` did not help either.

Comment: How is `maxIdx` declared?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From OpenCV [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#minmaxidx):

> When `minIdx` is not NULL, it must have at least 2 elements (as
>   well as `maxIdx`), even if src is a single-row or single-column matrix.

Comment: Thanks so much! Totally didn't see that :/